# How to fix texstudio gui compatibility in linux mint dual monitor setup?

Tags: texstudio, linux

My texstudio clickable menus do not pull up whenever I have the dual monitor setup on my linux mint computer. How to fix texstudio gui compatibility in linux mint dual monitor setup?

Comment: Ahm... could you be more specific, sincerely I don't understand your trouble. I understand your editor doesn't works fine when you're using a double display. If you think it's a bug you can [report it](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/) or ask for helping in [forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839) and also[ask in the mailist](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/texstudio-list). Perhaps there would be easier to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. When the two monitors have two very different resolutions for example 1280x1024 and 1200x1920 then the clickable menus do not appear on both monitors. However when I switched resolutions to 1680x1050 and 1200x1920, then the problem was fixed.